# How can I get the routeValue for an actionlink from a textbox? - asp-net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, actionlink

I wanted to add the sorting and filtering to my Application. (I want to organize some events) When I know search for an event with has an 'a' in it and than want to sort the results, all results are shown again and sorted.

I know, that I have to pass the searchString as a Routeparameter for the Actionlink. But how can I do this?

I found one solution with Request.Querystring but it hadn't work. 
Someone told me to do it with JavaScript, so I tried to write a function but it didn't work either.
Can anybody help me?

Excerpts from my code:

Actionlink:

```
    <h1>events</h1>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    <p>
        <lable>events:</lable>
        @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Titel", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm}, new { id = action})             
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

JavaScript-Function:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#action').click(function () {
            var s = $('#SearchString').val();
            this.href = this.href + '?searchString=' + encodeURIComponent(searchString);
        });
    });
</script >
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string searchString)
        {
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "titel_desc" : "";

            var vs = from t in _context.Events select t;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                vs = vs.Where(s => s.Titel.Contains(searchString));
            }

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "titel_desc":
                    vs = vs.OrderByDescending(m => m.Titel);
                    break;
                default:
                    vs = vs.OrderBy(m => m.Titel);
                    break;
            }
            return View(await vs.ToListAsync());
        }
```

Comment: What is your controller code? Does the action take a searchString paramter etc?

Comment: @John I edited my Controller code. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#action').click(function () {

        var search = $('#SearchString').val();
        //adding querystring to current URL
        var pageURL = $(location).attr("href") + "?searchString=" + encodeURIComponent(search);
        //reloading current URL with querystring
        window.location.href = pageURL;
   });
});
```

Comment: @niz173 is this you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net core document has explained how to do it clearly:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Try to specify controller and action for your Index View

```
<form asp-controller="Events" asp-action="Index" method="get">
<p>
    Title: <input type="text" name="SearchString">
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</p>
</form>

<table class="table">
</table>
```

Comment: still the same problem. If I want to sort the filtered events all events are shown again

Comment: @niz173 I could not reproduce and  do not  need to use the javascript function.So have you  gotten correct `sortOrder` and `searchString` in action?Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-2.2#add-filtering-functionality-to-the-index-method